# Provide nowrap for a radio button text

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the section below in a react component which has a column
in a grid. The text "My details in rows" wraps when I adjust the page.
How can I apply a style here such that this will not wrap again?

```
<Grid md container direction={'row'} spacing={1}>
    <Grid item md>
        <label>
            <input
                checked={
                    initialValues.tester.formatSetup
                        .fileFormat === 'row'
                }
                type='radio'
                name='tester.format.fileFormat'
                value='row'
                onChange={() => {
                    form.setFieldValue(
                        'tester.format.fileFormat',
                        'row'
                    )
                }}
            />
            {' My details in rows'}
            <div className={classes.fileFormat}>
                {Z21FileFormat('Row')}
            </div>
        </label>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: im not sure if this will work but does sth like this work? `<span style={{minWidth: 200}}>{' My details in rows'}</span>`

Comment: I eventually got it to work now using this  "white-space:nowrap". This might be useful for anyone else.

Comment: yes I thought of that too after writing the comment and I was about to write it as alternative :)